# c# Bitmap is already locked screenshots

Tags: c#, sockets, bitmap, screenshot

im trying to make a program that takes screen shots and compare them.

this is a sample of the code

compare method:

```
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, UIntPtr count);


  public bool CompareMemCmp(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
    {

        if ((b1 == null) != (b2== null)) return false;
        //  if (b1.Size != b2.Size) return false;



             var bd1 = b1.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b1.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bd2 = b2.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b2.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);


            IntPtr bd1scan0 = bd1.Scan0;
            IntPtr bd2scan0 = bd2.Scan0;

            int stride = bd1.Stride;
            int len = stride * b1.Height;

            return memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, (UIntPtr)(len)) == 0;


    }
```

thisis the main code:

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        prev = CaptureScreen.GetDesktopImage();
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(capture));
        th.Start();
    }

      private void capture()
    {


        while (true)
        {

            current = CaptureScreen.GetDesktopImage();

            if (CompareMemCmp(prev, current))
            {
              label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text="changed"));
                prev = current;
            }

            else
                label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "same"));

            count++;

        }


    }
```

im getting a weird error int the CompareMemCmp method at that line

```
 var bd1 = b1.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), b1.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

i guess it's related to the screenshot take.. cuz when i compare just 2 images from a directory it works fine... any idea how to relase them guys?

Comment: Are you using this library to capture it? http://www.csscript.net/samples/printscreen.cs.txt would be good to add the reference to your question.

Comment: How is the error weird? I see you lock the Bitmaps. Where do you unlock them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `UnlockBits()` on your bitmap after you are done with the comparing. See example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
...
int stride = bd1.Stride;
int len = stride * b1.Height;

b1.UnlockBits(bd1);
b2.UnlockBits(bd2);

return memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, (UIntPtr)(len)) == 0;
...
```

Comment: You should also change the line `if ((b1 == null) != (b2== null)) return false;` as it will not return with false if both of the references are `null`. I think you meant to write: `if ((b1 == null) || (b2 == null)) return false;`